# How to using linq asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

Could someone help me explaining how can I do this?

I need to list my products by categories (working fine at the moment), but now I need to check if each product listed is part of user's 'wishlist'. If yes, need to show a different icon color, for example.

[image]

Controller:

```
// Products Id
var produtosId = _context.Product
                         .Where(m => m.IdProdutoCategoria == idCategoria || 
                                     m.IdProdutoCategoriaNavigation.IdPai.Value == 1)
                         .Where(m => m.IsAtivo.Equals(true))
                         .GroupBy(m => m.Nome)
                         .Select(m => m.Min(p => p.IdProduto));

// products list
var products = await _context.Product
                             .Where(p => produtosId.Contains(p.IdProduto))
                             .Include(p => p.IdProdutoCategoriaNavigation)
                             .Include(p => p.IdProdutoTamanhoNavigation)
                             .Include(p => p.IdProdutoTipoMassaNavigation)
                             //.Include(p => p.WishList.Contains()
                             .ToListAsync()
                             .ConfigureAwait(true);

return View(products);
```

View:

```
@* WishList Icon *@
<div class="WishList" data-id="@item.IdProduto" style="cursor: pointer">
    <i class="@( item.XXXX == XX ? "fas fa-heart" : "far fa-heart") fa-1x text-success float-right mr-2 mb-2"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a case where viewmodels and projection come in handy. Add a field to the view model called, say, `IsOnWishList` and set it equal to `IsOnWishList = x.WishList.Any()`. Now you can use that value in Razor.

Comment: you need to get the whitelisted products grouped by category for a given users X  ?

Comment: Need the result for all products, for a given user. And some value to use in Razor to show like an icon when some products is at his wishlist. I will try the @SteveGreene sugestion.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
.Where(p => _context.WishList.Any(wl => wl.IdProduto == p.IdProduto))
```

```cs
var products = await _context.Product
        .Where(p => produtosId.Contains(p.IdProduto))
        .Include(p => p.IdProdutoCategoriaNavigation)
        .Include(p => p.IdProdutoTamanhoNavigation)
        .Include(p => p.IdProdutoTipoMassaNavigation)
        .Where(p => _context.WishList.Any(wl => wl.IdProduto == p.IdProduto))
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(true)
```

Comment: Need the result for all products, for a given user. And some value to use in Razor to show like an icon when some products is at his wishlist.